# Loop through directory and files with with date string to find the file with highest suffix (e.g. "firsttable_20230113093000_12")

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am looking to adapt a shell script to find a way to cycle through files that have different table names as well as different dates between files that have the same table name, and return the highest suffix file.

An example of my files in a given directory:

```
firsttable_20230112093000_1
firsttable_20230112093000_2
firsttable_20230112093000_3
firsttable_20230112093000_4
firsttable_19990202090000_1
firsttable_19990202090000_2
secondtable_20220112090000_1
secondtable_20220112090000_2
secondtable_20220112090000_3
```

**Desired Result:**

```
firsttable_20230112093000_4
firsttable_19990202090000_2
secondtable_20220112090000_3
```

**What's been done**

Originally I only needed to find the highest suffix as the dates would be the same for all tables, and what I had worked:

```
allTables=(
  'firsttable'
  'secondtable'
  'thirdtable'
  ...
  )

for table in ${allTables[@]}; do
  substring="_2"
  searchstring="$table$substring"
  # Check if the file for a given table exists:
  if ls $Path/$searchString* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$searchString* files exist. Proceeding..."
    lastFile=$(ls "$Path/searchString"* | sort -rV | head -n1)
    echo "Highest suffix file: $lastFile"
  else
    echo "File searchstring not found: '$Path/$searchString' "
  fi
done
```

If I was to apply that to my new directory shown above, it would only be able to find:

```
Highest suffix file: firsttable_20230112093000_4
Highest suffix file: secondtable_20220112090000_3
```

I need to find a way to make the script also look at the dates and see if they are different, and if they are, treat them as such. Would this require a regex to assess the filename? The filename format stays the same: "tablename_$$$$$$$$$$$$$$_nn" (underscore placing after table and date, suffix can go above single figures, date is always 14 characters)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: does `ls firsttable_* | sed 's/_[0-9][0-9]*$//' | sort -u` help? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is pretty easy to do with Awk. In brief, using underscore as separator, use the first two fields as the key, and collect the maximum in the value for each key in an associative array.

```
printf '%s\n' * |
awk -F _ 'a[$1 FS $2] < $3 { a[$1 FS $2] = $3 }
    END { for (k in a) print k FS a[k] }'
```

In some more detail, the `printf` command prints all the file names, one on each line. ([Don't use `ls` in scripts!)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) In the Awk script, the `-F` option sets the field separator, before we process the input; we then check on each line of input whether `a` contains a key which consists of the concatenation of the first field (the table name), the field separator (underscore), and the second field (the date stamp) and if so, if the value of this key is less than the third field. Conveniently for us, the value defaults to zero if the key is missing, so we are also capturing any keys which have not yet been defined, and populating the key. The end result will be that the maximum value of the suffix is collected for each pair of table name and date stamp; in the `END` section, which runs when there is no more input to read, we print out the collected values, formatted suitably to combine back into the original input.

Something similar could probably be done in Bash, but Awk is arguably more elegant and simple, as well as portable to basically any Unix system. In fact, the language is simple and easy enough that you could solve this problem yourself after spending an afternoon or less with a beginners' tutorial.

Comment: I also note that you didn't add the [tag:bash] tag to your question, even though your attempt is clearly a Bash (or Ksh) script; plain `sh` doesn't have arrays.